# Naive Bayes Classification with R - strange result

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, naivebayes

I have the following problem: I'd like to pedict a factor-variable "cancer" (yes or no) using two variables "sex" and "agegroup" with a bayes classifier.
These are my (fictional) sample data:

```
install.packages("e1071")
install.packages("gmodels")
library(e1071)
library(gmodels)

data<-read.csv("http://www.reduts.net/cancer.csv", sep=";", stringsAsFactors = T)

## Sex and Agegroup ##
######################

# classification 
testset<-data[,c("sex", "agegroup")]
cancer<-data[,"cancer"]
model<-naiveBayes(testset, cancer)
model

# apply model on testset
testset$predicted<-predict(model, testset)
testset$cancer<-cancer

CrossTable(testset$predicted, testset$cancer, prop.chisq=F, prop.r=F,    prop.c=F, prop.t = F)
```

The result shows me that according to my data males and younger people are more likely to have cancer. Compared to the real cancer-classification my model classifies 147 (=88+59) out of 200 cases correctly (73.5%).

```
                  | testset$original 
testset$predicted |        no |       yes | Row Total | 
------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
               no |        88 |        12 |       100 | 
------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
              yes |        54 |        46 |       100 | 
------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
     Column Total |       142 |        58 |       200 | 
------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
```

However, then I was doing the same thing using only one classification-variable (sex):

```
## Sex only         ##
######################

# classification 
testset2<-data[,c("sex")]
cancer<-data[,"cancer"]
model2<-naiveBayes(testset2, cancer)
model2
```

The model is as follows:

```
Naive Bayes Classifier for Discrete Predictors

Call:
naiveBayes.default(x = testset2, y = cancer)

A-priori probabilities:
cancer
   no   yes 
0.645 0.355 

Conditional probabilities:
      x
cancer         f         m
   no  0.4573643 0.5426357
   yes 0.5774648 0.4225352
```

Obviously, males are more likely to have cancer compared to females (54% vs 46%).

```
# apply model on testset
testset2$predicted<-predict(model2, testset2)
testset2$cancer<-cancer

CrossTable(testset2$predicted, testset2$cancer, prop.chisq=F, prop.r=F, prop.c=F, prop.t = F)
```

Now, when I apply my model to the original data, all cases are classified as the same class:

```
Total Observations in Table:  200 

                   | testset2$cancer 
testset2$predicted |        no |       yes | Row Total | 
-------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
                no |       129 |        71 |       200 | 
-------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
      Column Total |       129 |        71 |       200 | 
-------------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
```

**Can anyone please explain me, why both females and males are assigned to the same class**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misinterpreting those outputs. 
When you print out model2 and see

> ```
> Conditional probabilities:
>       x
> cancer         f         m
>    no  0.4573643 0.5426357
>    yes 0.5774648 0.4225352
> ```

It is wrong to conclude "Obviously, males are more likely 
to have cancer compared to females (54% vs 46%)."

What this table is telling us is the four numbers

> ```
> P(female | no cancer)     P(male | no cancer) 
> P(female | cancer)        P(male | cancer)
> ```

It is easy to see this by looking at the output of

> ```
> table(cancer, testset2)
>       testset2
> cancer  f  m
>    no  59 70
>    yes 41 30
> ```

The first line of conditional probabilities from the model can be computed as follows:
129 people do not have cancer. 59/129 = 0.4573643 are female.
70/129 = 0.5426357 are male. So the way to read that first line is 
"Given that a patient does not have cancer, they are more 
likely to be male (54% vs 46%)".

Now to your question: **Can anyone please explain me, why both 
females and males are assigned to the same class?**

To decide which class males will be assigned to, you need to compare
`P(Cancer | Male)` with `P(No Cancer | male)`. Whichever is bigger, 
we will declare to indicate the class. When using Naïve Bayes,  these 
are estimated by applying Bayes Rule to reformulate this as comparing

> ```
> P(Cancer | Male) = P(Male | Cancer) * P(Cancer) / P(Male)  
> with  
> P(No Cancer | Male) = P(Male | No Cancer) * P(No Cancer) / P(Male)
> ```

The denominators are the same in both cases,  so if we only care about
which is bigger, we can compare the size of

`P(Male | Cancer) * P(Cancer)`   with `P(Male | No Cancer) * P(No Cancer)`

These are *exactly* the figures being reported when you print out the model.

So,  for the males

```
P(Male | Cancer) * P(Cancer)        = 0.4225352 * 0.355 = 0.15
P(Male | No Cancer) * P(No Cancer)  = 0.5426357 * 0.645 = 0.35
```

(Note:  these are not real probabilities because we ignored the denominator
`P(Male)` )  Since No Cancer has the higher number, we predict No Cancer for males.

Similarly, for females we compute

```
P(Female | Cancer) * P(Cancer)      = 0.5774648 * 0.355 = 0.205
P(Female | No Cancer) * P(No Cancer)    = 0.4573643 * 0.645 = 0.295
```

and for females too we predict no cancer. It may be useful to emphasize this
calculation for females. Even though `P(Female | Cancer) > P(Female | No Cancer)`, 
these are weighted by the overall probabilities `P(Cancer)` and `P(No Cancer)`.
Since overall it is more likely to have No Cancer rather than Cancer, that 
switches which is bigger. Naïve Bayes predicts No Cancer for both genders.